# How to solve "Character content other than whitespace is not allowed" in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I got exception in my Magento 2.4.1 site when I load front end. I can't understand from where this error throwing out. How to find the error location.

[image]

full exception right below

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'arguments': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 1492


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'arguments': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 1492

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:512]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:488]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php:149]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:259]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:884]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:293]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php:218]
#15 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Noroute/Index.php:47]
#16 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#18 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php:51]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#20 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#21 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php:23]
#22 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#24 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#25 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#26 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php:32]
#27 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:186]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#32 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:75]
#34 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#39 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
```

please help me to find out this issue.
Thanks